# C++ illegal digit, simple issue

Tags: c++

I'm running against this error:

```
int temp = 0789;

error C2041: illegal digit '8' for base '8'
```

For what I can understand is that the compiler understands any number that begins with 0 like 0123 to be octal. But how can I tell the compiler to just take it with the 0 in front?

Comment: Why must you put a 0 in front?  It won't change how the number is displayed.

Comment: You can't "tell" the compiler that I'm afraid.  (Imagine the confusion involved in interpreting code if you somehow could...)  You need to get rid of the leading 0, simple as that.

Comment: @Overseer10: Do you mean you want it displayed in your output with a 0 in front of it?

Comment: No, I need it to be stored inside the variable with the 0 in front. The variable won't be displayed.

Comment: @Overseer10: `int` (and other such numeric types) don't store leading zeros. They store numeric values. The numeric value of 789 with or without a leading zero is exactly the same.

Comment: To be precise: computers use binary. I.e. 789 is `0000001100010101` (if `int` is 16 bits, else you have even more leading zeroes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf(v=vs.80).aspx

Great resource about this.

0xff is hex
0123 is octal
123u is unsigned
..lots more...

Answer (score 6):

If you put 0 in front it believes its an octal value, thus 8 and 9 are illegal digits.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a 0 at the front of the number tells the compiler that the value is expressed in octal; octal digits are only 0 through 7, so '789' is not a valid octal number.  The only solution here is to remove the 0 from the beginning of the number (assuming you meant to have the number be in decimal).... or provide a valid octal number (if you really meant to use octal).

Well, I suppose you could do this:

```
int temp = atoi("0789");
```

But that will be rather inefficient, since the value will be computed from the string at run-time, rather than compiled in directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display your number with a zero in front of it, just do this:

```
int temp = 789;
std::cout << '0' << temp;
```

If you want to pad any arbitrary number with zeroes so that it's 4 digits, then you can do this(being sure to include `<iomanip>`)

```
int temp = 789;
std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << temp;
```